# Div shadow is not showing and appearing side by side

Tags: html, css

For some reason Div block shadow is not showing and the last block's shadow is appearing side by side. I don't know what else I need to do. I have z-index and position set to relative but it's still not working as expected.

Edit: I want the blocks to be side by side and responsible.

```css
.main {
  padding-top: 10px;
  -moz-column-count: 4;
  -moz-column-gap: 0;
  -webkit-column-count: 4;
  -webkit-column-gap: 0;
  column-count: 4;
  column-gap: 0;
}

.main .columnBlock {
  background-color: #fff;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 0 4px 8px 8px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px #d4d6d8;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px #d4d6d8;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px #d4d6d8;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 999;
}

.column {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 140px;
  width: 22%;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-top: 8px;
}

.column ul {
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.column ul {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  height: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-device-width: 9999px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    float: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main" style="width: 100%;">
  <div class="columnBlock">
    <div class="column">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Data 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Data 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Data 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- .columnBlock -->

  <div class="columnBlock">
    <div class="column">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Data 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Data 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Data 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- .columnBlock -->

</div>
<!-- .main -->
```

Comment: The problem is with the column gap/count styles.. if you comment them out and run the code, the box shadow appears fine. Are you using Bootstrap? Foundation?

Comment: @Kyle1323 you're correct. However, I want the blocks to be side by side. If I remove the count/gap, the first block is taking the whole window while the second one goes below the first one. And no, I'm not using bootstrap or Foundation. It's all custom.

Comment: you can add display:flex; to the main class. https://jsfiddle.net/suunyz3e/1398/

Comment: take a look at this version, i think you can simplify you code a little https://jsfiddle.net/suunyz3e/1399/

Comment: @omer the problem with display:flex is that all blocks are showing up in one row as columns, try adding additional blocks you will see what I'm talking about. I need them to be responsible - when on mobile I want 2 columns, on tablets I want 3, and on desktop I want 4 columns.

Comment: @bluechipmonk if you want them to be responsive, you need to add media queries and set the width of the columns at different screen sizes (50%, 33.333% and 25%, respectively to your 2, 3 and 4 columns)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're looking for. I removed the column count and gap, and just using margin and floats with `@media` queries. I added two more columns so you can see it in action.

HTML:

```
<div class="main" style="width: 100%;">
  <div class="columnBlock">
    <div class="column">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Data 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Data 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Data 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- .columnBlock -->

  <div class="columnBlock">
    <div class="column">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Data 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Data 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Data 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- .columnBlock -->

  <div class="columnBlock">
    <div class="column">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Data 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Data 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Data 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- .columnBlock -->

  <div class="columnBlock">
    <div class="column">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Data 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Data 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Data 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- .columnBlock -->

</div>
<!-- .main -->
```

CSS:

```
.main {
  padding-top: 10px;
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.main .columnBlock {
  background-color: #fff;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 0 4px 8px 8px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px #d4d6d8;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px #d4d6d8;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px #d4d6d8;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 999;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:767px) {
  .columnBlock {
    width: calc(50% - 10px);
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:768px) {
  .columnBlock {
    width: calc(33.3333% - 10px);
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:992px) {
  .columnBlock {
    width: calc(25% - 10px);
  }
}

.column {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-top: 8px;
}

.column ul {
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.column ul {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  height: 100%;
}
```

And here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u2h1cwzt/3/

All your shadows are where they are supposed to be and it's responsive.

Edit: added display: flex, to prevent gaps.

EDIT: Without Flex: https://jsfiddle.net/u2h1cwzt/4/

CSS: WITHOUT FLEX

```
.main {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.main .columnBlock {
  background-color: #fff;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 0 4px 8px 8px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px #d4d6d8;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px #d4d6d8;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px #d4d6d8;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 999;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:767px) {
  .columnBlock {
    width: calc(50% - 10px);
  }

  .columnBlock:nth-of-type(odd) {
    clear: left;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:768px) {
  .columnBlock {
    width: calc(33.3333% - 10px);
  }

  .columnBlock:nth-of-type(odd) {
    clear: none;
  }

  .columnBlock:nth-of-type(3n+1) {
    clear: left;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:992px) {
  .columnBlock {
    width: calc(25% - 10px);
    clear: none !important;
  }

}

.column {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-top: 8px;
}

.column ul {
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.column ul {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: oh man, it kinda works but, try adding extra data like Data 4, Data 5 on the first block. It's moving the block below..

Comment: look at the top right block, there is white space on the bottom within the block

Comment: Yeah, you can't really avoid that, especially since you want it responsive.

Comment: @bluechipmonk checkout the latest fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u2h1cwzt/4/ This may get you what you want without the whitespace.

Comment: yea but I don't want any long gaps between blocks though

Comment: What you're asking for is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

i think this is what you are looking for (if i understood right). i added angularjs ng-repeat but it's just for convenient. there is also a link for a version with only html and css.

link1 - with angular https://jsfiddle.net/suunyz3e/1408/

link2 - only html and css https://jsfiddle.net/suunyz3e/1410/

html:

```
<div ng-app="myModule" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <div class="div-item" ng-repeat="item in loopArray">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="">Data 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Data 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Data 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

css:

```
.div-item{
  display:inline-block;
  min-width:140px;
  background-color:#fff;
  margin:5px;
  border:1px solid red;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px #d4d6d8;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px #d4d6d8;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px #d4d6d8;
}
```

angualrjs

```
angular.module('myModule', [])

.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {

   $scope.loopArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]

});
```

Comment: Try adding additionals Datas to one of the blocks on second or third row. You will see there will be gaps, I don't need those gaps. Maybe disinfor is right, it's probably not possible with plain css and html